# Spyder Anaconda launch error

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

When I installed the Anaconda python distribution in Ubuntu 16.04LTS, it doesn't launch and giving below error.

```
Studio-XPS-1640:~$ spyder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/spyder", line 3, in <module>
    start_app.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/start_app.py", line 114, in main
    from spyderlib import spyder
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/spyder.py", line 155, in <module>
    from spyderlib.utils.environ import WinUserEnvDialog
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/utils/environ.py", line 17, in <module>
    from spyderlib.widgets.dicteditor import DictEditor
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/dicteditor.py", line 39, in <module>
    from spyderlib.widgets.dicteditorutils import (sort_against, get_size,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/dicteditorutils.py", line 78, in <module>
    import bs4
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/builder/__init__.py", line 314, in <module>
    from . import _html5lib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/builder/_html5lib.py", line 70, in <module>
    class TreeBuilderForHtml5lib(html5lib.treebuilders._base.TreeBuilder):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_base'
```

How to solve this and what could be the reason for the error.

Comment: Also it is pointing to python 2.7 I want to point it to python 3..

Comment: Which version of anaconda you have downloaded 3.6 or 2.7?

Comment: I think there was a problem in the version of anaconda.. I have python 3 and anaconda was python 2. I re-installed python3 anaconda.. The issue was resolved.

Comment: Cool, Yeah I know that's way I am asking the version of anaconda...